# Angular reportProgress event with http.post not working

Tags: angular

Is it possible to use reportProgress with http.post? Angular has its http request set up differently in their HttpClient section (https://angular.io/guide/http)
My service provider is set up like this:

```
postForm(shortForm: any): Observable<ShortFormModel> {
 let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
 let options = new RequestOptions({
  headers: headers
});

return this.http.post(this.preCheckUrl, shortForm, options)     
  .map((res) => this.extractData(res))
  .catch(
  (error: any): Promise<any>=> {
    console.error('An error occurred', error); 
    this.router.navigate(['/error', error]);
    return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
  }
)
}

private extractData(res: Response) {
  let body = res.json();     
  return body || { };
}
```

I've tried adding `reportProgress: true` to the options but I get the error: `Argument of type '{ headers: Headers; reportProgress: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestOptionsArgs'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'reportProgress' does not exist in type 'RequestOptionsArgs'.`

Comment: Are you using angular v4.3 and importing the new http client? import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';

Comment: Nope, v4.2.2. Was that feature only released in 4.3?

Comment: Correct, it is a v4.3+ feature only available in the new http module

Comment: Should have checked release notes first. Is it recommended to use the new HttpClientModule?

Comment: I haven't looked into the stability of it, but I believe for most use cases it is safe to start using. Eventually the old http module will be deprecated, so you will have to move over at some point.